# Windows Phone 8.1 - Building image gallery from pictures library images

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make an image gallery from pictures library images. Everything is working fine when I have a reduced number of images, but if I have more than 80 images, the phone runs out of memory. I've tried using data virtualization by defining a class which implements the ISupportIncrementalLoading interface. Then I used that class to populate my GridView, but with absolutely no luck: it still is throwing an OutOfMemoryException.
The possibility I'm thinking about is to use random access virtualization, but I haven't found any code template about it.
So,
Could you please explain me how to apply random access virtualization to my list of images?
Or
Could you please explain me how to effectively make an image gallery which retrieves its elements from the Phone's photo gallery?

My XAML code is as follows:

```
<GridView x:Name="photosGrid" Height="392" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,-0.333,0" SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="Black">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Width="90" Height="90" Margin="5" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                </GridView>
```

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding}" may be suspicious depending on how your view model is structured.

Comment: I simply get a List<ImageSource> from all the images on KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFilesAsync() and set that list as the GridView's Data Context